# PHP exec_shell via input string

Tags: php, shell-exec

I can use shell_exec this way:

```php
$output = shell_exec('ls -lart');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

but this did'nt work:

```php
$job = 'ls -lart';
$output = shell_exec($job);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Is'nt it possible to give a string to shell_exec?

Comment: check if your php isn't running in safe mode

Comment: Checked: PHP Version is 7.3., - there's no safe_mode anymore.

Comment: Yes, It is possible to give a string to shell_exec. Can you please share what errors you are getting?

Comment: There are no errors. echo $output show only the given string ...

Comment: Check the php error log

Comment: errorlog said: Der Befehl "$job" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden - sound to me like: The content of the variable was not interpreted but misunderstood as a command

Answer (score 0):

Work. Error was not shell_exec, but wrong concatination of two string given to it ...

Comment: Sounds like a typo/syntax error in that case, one that the MVCE didn't replicate. I think the question should be removed in this case.